# pass back the pid from child to parent

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing a C++ program that allow run multiple programm in the background and mangament them at the same time.

It suppose print a message that some background program has been finish. Since I cannot directly print the finish msg in the child process, so I try to print it using wait() in parent, it works but I cannot get the child PID, so the output msg is wrong.

Is there any method to let me get child pid and print it by parent?

```
if(cmdline=="bg"){//bg

  pid=fork();

  if (pid == 0){ // child process

    char * parmList[] = {"demo","running","2","3",NULL};
    execvp(parmList[0],parmList);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

  }
  else if (pid > 0){// preant
        pidStack.push_back(pid);
        nameStack.push_back(argTemp[0]);
        wait(&status);
        cout << getpid() << " completed" << endl;

  }   


  else { // fork failed
    printf("fork () failed!\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
 }
```

Comment: The parent obtains the child's pid from `fork()` (its return value). So, you have it already stored in the `pid` variable.

Comment: Read the documentation for wait(). It tells you exactly where to find the pid of the terminated child process.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the point of the return value of `fork`. That **is** the child pid !

You're currently printing `getpid` in the parent, but that of course prints the parent pid.